# local variable 'browser' referenced before assignment in python-selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I knew there is lot of same questions-answer available but give me some opportunity to explain I thought it is not with some referencing issue,

Requirement: we have E2E test running already on every 1 hour in Linux VM, but from today it is failing, below is code snippet that set 'browser' variable,

```
    import webdriver_manager.chrome
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    try:         
       chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
       chrome_opt.add_argument('--headless')
       chrome_opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
       # raise Exception(f'inside test error: for re-producing above error')
       browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                               chrome_opt=chrome_opt)
       # some e2e test-cases

    except TimeoutException as ex:
        browser.quit()
        raise Exception(f'Time-out exception {str(ex)}')
    except Exception as ex:
        browser.quit()
        raise Exception(f'Error while testing user interface: {str(ex)}')
```

Above code reside is in same file 'test.py' with specific and generic block to catch exception so before line number 7 there is some weird error is generated and that's why exception is raised.

Now the problem is here exception 'local variable 'browser' referenced before assignment' is not caught by above 2 exception blocks(basically generic block) instead it is caught in caller/parent file name as 'main_ui.py' and there generic block.

Here my intention/objective to caught above exception in generic block of same file i.e. 'test.py' and do something like this,

```
except Exception as ex:
    if browser is not None: 
      browser.quit()
    raise Exception(f'Error while testing user interface: {str(ex)}')
```

Someone can help here to find out **why this error is raised** and **how to avoid if possible** and **if not then how to caught Exception in generic block of same file** i.e. here test.py or even any other solution that helps here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_opt=chrome_opt)` has an exception, no value is assigned to browser. The variable is hence never declared and does not exist.

Set it to None before the try block

```
    import webdriver_manager.chrome
    from selenium import webdriver

    browser = None
    try:         
       chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
       chrome_opt.add_argument('--headless')
       chrome_opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
       # raise Exception(f'inside test error: for re-producing above error')
       browser = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                               chrome_opt=chrome_opt)
       # some e2e test-cases

    except TimeoutException as ex:
        if browser is not None: browser.quit()
        raise Exception(f'Time-out exception {str(ex)}')
    except Exception as ex:
        if browser is not None: browser.quit()
        raise Exception(f'Error while testing user interface: {str(ex)}')
```